# How do I read from Hive using Apache Beam?

Tags: hive, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

How to read from Hive using Apache Beam / how to use Hive as a source in Apache Beam ?

Comment: Post an answer instead of putting the the answer together with the quesion

Answer (score 0):

HadoopInputFormatIO can be used to read from Hive as below :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setClass("mapreduce.job.inputformat.class", HCatInputFormat.class, 
InputFormat.class);
conf.setClass("key.class", LongWritable.class, WritableComparable.class);
conf.setClass("value.class", DefaultHCatRecord.class, Writable.class);
conf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "...");
HCatInputFormat.setInput(hiveConf, "myDatabase", "myTable", "myFilter");


PCollection<KV<LongWritable, DefaultHCatRecord>> data =
p.apply(HadoopInputFormatIO.<Long, 
DefaultHCatRecord>read().withConfiguration(conf));
```

Comment: Can you please share pom? and also full code of key value classes?

Answer (score 0):

A pull request merged in July 2017 allows `Beam 2.1.0` to support `hive` via the `HCatalog` https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2357 .